# Socket connection from compiled c.cgi

Tags: c, sockets, cgi

On linux I want to connect to a demon, via a socket in a compiled c.cgi program (cgic), which is listening for incoming socket connections. I know the server works because it will responded to 'nc' commands. Assume the server is black-boxed, I can't change it. In my client program I have:

```
int sockfd;
int len;
struct sockaddr_in address;
int result;
char ch[] = "get=DeviceNo";

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
address.sin_port = 3042;
len = sizeof(address);
result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, len);
```

Which returns with a "Connection Refused" error at this point. As a test I compiled the netcat into the .cgi program which does work:

```
system("echo '-r get=DeviceNo' | nc localhost 3042");
```

Am I missing something maybe how the socket class is handled within a .cgi? What should I do to try and get this socket to connect or what can I do to further troubleshoot my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `sockaddr_in` type, you need to know that both socket address `sin_addr.s_addr` and port `sin_port` must be in network byte order. Most likely your host is little-endian.

So you need to use `inet_addr` returns correct value, but for the socket address you need to use:

```
address.sin_port = htons(3042);
```

Comment: Thanks checked the server code and that was my issue.